# Creating an embed application for other sites

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, embed

I have an application in mind that I want to build using ruby on rails, however, after I build it I want to be able to allow other websites to embed the application into there sites.

For example, a live chat system, normally these can be embedded using a `script` or `iframe`, which sounds the best way to embed, however, how could I make my application embeddable using these methods using my own databases and whatnot.

I think there is a process name but I can't think of it or rather the best way to go about it.

Comment: Do you mean like a Rails Engine?

Comment: 'cause if you don't mean a rails engine, then this really isn't a rails question.  More of a x-site security/HTML question